# validate a date in dd/mm/yyyy format

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to validate a date with regex but its failing, i am trying to use it to write it in input manually or select from a calendar on the side

```
<input type="text" name="FromDate"  value="28/8/2022" id="Strtcalfield1" REQUIRED="yes" VALIDATE="date" MESSAGE="Please enter date (dd/MM/yyyy)." pattern="/^(\s{0,})(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})(,\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}){1,}(\s){0,}$" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter date (dd/mm/yyyy).')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')"/>
```

and that is throwing an error

value is coming from backend, but when i choose rom calendar, it keeps on giving me an error

please enter date as `dd/mm/yyyy` as i see the date is correctly entered

Comment: Use RegExp to validate string format

Comment: *"but when i choose rom calendar,"* What calendar script/plugin/widget are you using? What does its documentation say about how to set the date format?

Comment: Your regex seems ok, somewhat lackluster in validating that it's a real date (can pick 88 as the date) but it'll still check for correct format. My guess is that the calendar library does not give the format you are expecting.

Comment: configure the calendar library to enter the dates in `dd/mm/yyyy` format

Comment: Why are you using `input type=text` when you can use `input type=date`?

Comment: if the regex is correct, i get a message on requires-yes, which shows the message on oninvalid

Comment: @ControlAltDel normally to use a styled third-party date picker rather than some random ugly one from the browser.

Comment: @freedomn-m If I was the tech leader of the project and someone came to me and said we want to use this custom date picker because it's "stylish" they would hear the riot act. IMO concerns over code base size / support / maintainability are all more important to me than "stylish"... OP is lucky (I suppose) that I'm not sitting in his/her manager's seat :)

Comment: @ControlAltDel interesting, similarly, if I was the UX designer of a project and had spent untold hours designing and developing a consistent look and feel, with emphasis on usability, across an entire suite of applications, then some tech lead said, "we're just gonna using the built in pig-ugly date picker".... well, you get the rest ;)

Comment: @freedomn-m re: UX designer - If it were up to me, I wouldn't let the UX peoples anywhere near JavaScript - I'd keep them all strictly on CSS :) the vulnerabilities associated with JavaScript (IMO) do not come anywhere close to the value of having a super-clean UX. And you can use CSS to style the input date picker popup (though with some limitations) using CSS. But look, I don't want to argue with you. It's a matter of perspective - you have yours and I have mine.

Comment: @ControlAltDel no arguing, just letting you know why they might use `type='text'`.  Interesting to see different perspectives.

Comment: Show what you have tried and the specific challenge you have with it and add more details beyond just the HTML perhaps.  Add your error for "and that is throwing an error" as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could validate the string with a JavaScript function instead of the regex pattern to ensure that it is a valid date. The following function parses the `dd/mm/yyyy` string pattern and ensures the day part is in the correct range for the parsed month and year values.

```
function validateDateString(dateString) {
   // regex for date string format: dd/mm/yyyy
   const dateFormatRegex = /^(0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[01])[\/](0?[1-9]|1[0-2])[\/]\d{4}$/;
   let isValidDate = false;
   if (dateString.match(dateFormatRegex)) {
      const dateParts = dateString.split('/');
      if (dateParts.length == 3) {
         const day = parseInt(dateParts[0]);
         const month = parseInt(dateParts[1]);
         const year = parseInt(dateParts[2]);
         // valid month range is 1 - 12
         if (month < 1 || month > 12) {
            return false;
         }
         // validate days in month
         const daysInMonth = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31];
         let monthLength = daysInMonth[month-1];
         if ((month == 2) && ((!(year%4) && year%100) || !(year%400))) {
            monthLength = 29;
         }
         if (day < 1 || day > monthLength) {
            return false;
         }
         // checks have passed
         isValidDate = true;
      }
   }
   return isValidDate;
}
```

**EDIT:** The following modifications will allow the code to handle the date format of the locale used in the browser.

The `getLocaleDateFormat` function determines the locale date format by generating a unique date and identifying the position of each element in the locale string. The date separator character is also identified and the information is returned in a single object with keys: `day`, `month`, `year` and `sep`.

```
function getLocaleDateFormat() {
  const dummyDate = new Date(1999,11,30).toLocaleDateString().replace(/1999/,"yyyy").replace(/30/,"dd").replace(/12/,"mm");

  const findDateSegmentIndex = (pos) => {
     let index = -1;
     if (pos == 0) {
        index = 0;
     }
     else if ((pos > 0) & (pos < 6)) {
        index = 1;
     }
     else if ((pos > 5) & (pos < 10)) {
        index = 2;
     }
     return index;
  };

  const localeInfo = {
     "day": findDateSegmentIndex(dummyDate.search("dd")),
     "month": findDateSegmentIndex(dummyDate.search("mm")),
     "year": findDateSegmentIndex(dummyDate.search("yyyy")),
     "sep": dummyDate[dummyDate.search(/\W/)] 
  };

  return localeInfo;
}
```

The `getDateStringFormat` function uses the information in the object returned by `getLocaleDateFormat()` to assemble a string to create the regular expression which will match the locale date format. The object returned by the function includes the regular expression string in the `regex` key.

```
function getDateStringFormat() {
  const dateLocale = getLocaleDateFormat();
  const regexStringsObject = {
     "day": '(0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[01])',
     "month": '(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])',
     "year": '\\d{4}'
  }
  let regexElements = ['', '', ''];
  regexElements[ dateLocale["day"] ] = regexStringsObject["day"];
  regexElements[ dateLocale["month"] ] = regexStringsObject["month"];
  regexElements[ dateLocale["year"] ] = regexStringsObject["year"];
  const dateStringFormat = { ...dateLocale, 
     "regex": `^${regexElements[0]}[.\\-\\/]${regexElements[1]}[.\\-\\/]${regexElements[2]}$`
  };
  return dateStringFormat;
}
```

The updated `validateDateString` function uses the regex string in the object returned by `getDateStringFormat()` to parse the provided `dateString`. There are three different separators (`-`, `.`, `/`) handled. The locale date format information as determined in the `getLocaleDateFormat` function is used to validate the respective part of the date string.

```
function validateDateString(dateString) {
  const dateFormat = getDateStringFormat();
  let result = false;
  const regex = new RegExp(dateFormat.regex);
  if (dateString.match(regex)) {
     const dateParts = dateString.split(/[.\-\/]/);
     if (dateParts.length == 3) {
        const day = parseInt(dateParts[dateFormat.day]);
        const month = parseInt(dateParts[dateFormat.month]);
        const year = parseInt(dateParts[dateFormat.year]);
        // valid month range is 1 - 12
        if (month < 1 || month > 12) {
           return false;
        }
        // validate days in month
        const daysInMonth = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31];
        let monthLength = daysInMonth[month-1];
        if ((month == 2) && ((!(year%4) && year%100) || !(year%400))) {
           monthLength = 29;
        }
        if (day < 1 || day > monthLength) {
           return false;
        }
        // checks have passed
        result = true;
     }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: such kind of code then i also need for mm/dd/yyyy, since i have two formats to verify based upon the locale, can we do something in this function itself to pass an extra paramter which one checks for `dd/mm/yyyy` and other one is for `mm/dd/yyyy` and i am trying to use it on onpropertychange but this event is only for IE, i am trying to use something similar but which covers all browsers

Comment: I've updated the answer to include a solution that uses the locale date format of the web browser.

Comment: Thanks for the code, first off, i need only one seperator and that is `/`, apart from that, major concern is how does it validate, looking like an event `onpropertychange` but that unfortunately only work in the `IE`, i am looking for something which works with all browsers

Comment: The `change` event fires when the input field loses focus and the value has been changed. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event